# Simulink PDE (MATLAB)

Tags: pde, matlab

I need to build a system in Simulink that solves a PDE, but I can't find any literature or books where it is described how to do it (especially any stuff according to modeling PDE in Simulink).

Please give some advice where I can find such literature.

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SciComp. Could you give some more details on the problem itself? What PDE? What application?

Comment: I need to make a model in Simulink, this model must solve an equation 
$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}-\operatorname{div}\left(A(x)\nabla u(x,t)\right)=f(x,t),\text{where } A(x) \text{ is a matrix 2x2} $$ - general equation of diffusion in $(x_{1},x_{2},t)$. 
I have an experience in building models of ODEs in Simulink, but I have any idea what to do in this case. So that I'm trying to find someone who can help me.

Comment: AFAIK, Simulink is inherently focused on ODEs, and I know of now possibility to directly simulate PDEs. You may manually discretize the model spatially, although that's cumbersome in Simulink.

Comment: @FlorianBrucker, although it's cumbersome, but I would like to try it. Could you give me the source, where you saw the method how to do it?

Comment: I don't have a source or an example. Discretize your space dimensions using [method of lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_lines) or [finite differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference). This yields a system of ODEs which you can implement in Simulink. An application that I know is simulating heat flow in a rod, where the continuous rod is discretized into a low number (~10) of 0d nodes. Note that such things are much easier in Modelica, because it allows you to vary the number of nodes via a parameter.

Comment: MATLAB has a PDE toolbox that could handle 2D diffusion problems.

Comment: I have already known about it, but I am also interested how to do it in Simulink